# I need to compare text fields and bring numeric (value) results depending on the matching

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a base sheet where I have a drop-down using 4 text options (ALIVE, DEAD, WALKER, NON-WALKER) - This is for a GoT Deadpool game.

I will create a new sheet for each player who joins with the same options. Then I need to compare his choices to the baseline on the first sheet and return the following matches:
If both are ALIVE - return the number 1 (for 1 point)
If both are DEAD - return the number 1 again
If both are WALKER - return 2 but if it differs return -1 (a point is taken)
If both are NON-WALKER - results are same as the above for WALKER

Quoting the official rules for better understanding:
"If you predict the character dead, you have the option to predict if they become a White Walker. Gain one point if you correctly predict if they become a Walker. Lose a point if you predict incorrectly."

How can I do that? Which formula to use?

Thank you in advance, people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(AND(A2="ALIVE",      player1sheet!A2= "ALIVE"),      1,
 IF(AND(A2="DEAD",       player1sheet!A2= "DEAD"),       1,
 IF(AND(A2="WALKER",     player1sheet!A2= "WALKER"),     2,
 IF(AND(A2="WALKER",     player1sheet!A2<>"WALKER"),    -1,
 IF(AND(A2="NON-WALKER", player1sheet!A2= "NON-WALKER"), 2, )))))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay, this works almost perfectly. Thank you!
Now that I know the code I believe I should have no issues editing it. Will write back if a bit more help is needed!
Thanks a lot, again.